# html vertical align text in vertical menu

Tags: html, css

The idea is to have a vertical menu on the left, and near it to the right i have a banner (image) with text and button on it.

I have the following html/css code

```css
      .banner {
        position: relative;
      }
      .BannerImage {
        width: 70%;
        height: 400px;
        float: right;
      }
      .bannerTXT {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 170px;
        left: 420px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
      }
      .bannerBtn {
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 310px;
        left: 650px;
      }
      .CategoryMenu ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 250px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .CategoryMenu li a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        padding: 8px 0px 30px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .CategoryMenu li a:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
      }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img id="imgBanner" class="BannerImage" alt="" src="../Images/MainPic.jpg" />
  <div class="bannerTXT">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text
    <br />More Text Text Text Text Text
  </div>
  <p>
    <asp:Button ID="banBtn" class="buttons bannerBtn" runat="server" Text="How it works" />
  </p>
  <div class="CategoryMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Clothes & Shoes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Jewelry & Watches</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Cosmetics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Children</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't manage to vertically center the text in the menu under the class `CategoryMenu` i tried everything suggested in google, can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not changing your `padding` to this?

```css
.CategoryMenu li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 19px 0px 19px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

In stead of `padding: 8px 0px 30px 16px;`

**DEMO**

```css
.banner {
        position: relative;
      }
      .BannerImage {
        width: 70%;
        height: 400px;
        float: right;
      }
      .bannerTXT {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: 170px;
        left: 420px;
        width: 600px;
        height: 50px;
      }
      .bannerBtn {
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 310px;
        left: 650px;
      }
      .CategoryMenu ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 250px;
        height: 400px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
      }
      .CategoryMenu li a {
        display: block;
        color: black;
        padding: 19px 0px 19px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      .CategoryMenu li a:hover {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
      }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img id="imgBanner" class="BannerImage" alt="" src="../Images/MainPic.jpg" />
  <div class="bannerTXT">
    Text Text Text Text Text Text
    <br />More Text Text Text Text Text
  </div>
  <p>
    <asp:Button ID="banBtn" class="buttons bannerBtn" runat="server" Text="How it works" />
  </p>
  <div class="CategoryMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Clothes & Shoes</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Jewelry & Watches</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Home & Garden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Beauty & Cosmetics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Children</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG... i feel so stupid, i looked for everything and not realized that the answer is right in front of me, thank you very much, i will mark this as the answer in few minutes

Comment: Haha no problem! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the same value at top & bottom padding property.

```
.CategoryMenu li a {
   padding-top: 30px 0px 30px 16px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to align it dynamically and not deliberately add padding or margins, you can alter the `line-height` and the text will automatically center itself vertically accordingly.

https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/zyw756st/

This is generally useful for vertically centering things, essentially occupying the entire height and letting the browser stick it in the middle.